# Two launcher icons has inappropriate behaviour when app is in background

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher, android-launcher, launcher-icon

My android app has 2 launcher icons.

I am clicking the launcher icon 1 which open the first activity.

When i take the app to background by hitting home button & click on launcher icon 2, I am seeing the App is being bought to foreground instead of opening the activity corresponding to launcher icon 2.

But I have requirement to open the corresponding activity even if the app is in background.

I tried setting android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" & using onNewIntent, but this is not being trigger when app is resumed via launcher icon 2. Could some one help me on how to solve this?

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (10945) for package com.example.twolaunchericonapplication ----------------------------
//click on launcher icon 1
2023-10-17 07:51:09.581 10945-10945 First                   com...le.twolaunchericonapplication  E  onCreate
2023-10-17 07:51:09.602 10945-10945 First                   com...le.twolaunchericonapplication  E  onResume: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.twolaunchericonapplication/.MainActivity bnds=[582,785][859,1205] }
// click launcher icon 1 again
2023-10-17 07:51:22.113 10945-10945 First                   com...le.twolaunchericonapplication  E  onNewIntentIntent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10600000 cmp=com.example.twolaunchericonapplication/.MainActivity bnds=[582,785][859,1205] }
2023-10-17 07:51:22.113 10945-10945 First                   com...le.twolaunchericonapplication  E  onResume: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.twolaunchericonapplication/.MainActivity bnds=[582,785][859,1205] }
// click launcher icon 2
2023-10-17 07:51:31.277 10945-10945 First                   com...le.twolaunchericonapplication  E  onResume: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.twolaunchericonapplication/.MainActivity bnds=[582,785][859,1205] }
```

```
      <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="First Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TwoLauncherIconApplication">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:label="Second Activity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TwoLauncherIconApplication">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        Log.e("First","onNewIntent"+intent)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.e("First","onResume: "+intent)
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.e("First","onCreate")
        setContent {
            TwoLauncherIconApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("First")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
class SecondActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        Log.e("Second","onNewIntent"+intent)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.e("Second","onResume :"+intent)
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.e("Second","onCreate")
        setContent {
            TwoLauncherIconApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Second")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    TwoLauncherIconApplicationTheme {
        Greeting("Second")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use launchMode="singleTask"

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="First Activity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TwoLauncherIconApplication">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="Second Activity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TwoLauncherIconApplication">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

or use [taskAffinity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#aff) if you want to have several tasks.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="First Activity"
    android:taskAffinity="com.example.twolaunchericonapplication.MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TwoLauncherIconApplication">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="Second Activity"
    android:taskAffinity="com.example.twolaunchericonapplication.SecondActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TwoLauncherIconApplication">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```